# Permission redirecting error in CakePHP's AuthComponent

Tags: php, cakephp, authorization

I have seen many similar problems here in SO but none have helped me solving my problem.

I don't think CakePHP's AuthComponent is behaving properly when it comes to permission errors.

My CakePHP app is in a subdomain of my website (e.g. http://www.example.com/myapp). Everytime a permission error occurs (user is not allowed to see this page), Cake adds another "/myapp" in the URL (so it becomes http://www.example.com/myapp/myapp) and naturally throws an error which says that "myapp" controller doesn't exist.

In my scenario, the login view is linked to the root of the website. So, I have in my AppController:

```
public $components = array(
    'Session',
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
        'authorize' => 'Controller',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'email')
            )
        )
    )
);
```

And in routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
Router::connect('/users', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));

Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));
```

All I want is to be able to configure manually which URL Cake should redirect to in case of permission errors. Anybody knows how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry guys, I accidentally found the answer a bit later. As CakePHP has some very intuitive labels, I started guessing some possible options for the Auth Component that would solve my problem. And I ended up discovering the `unauthorizedRedirect` option!

So I have:

```
'unauthorizedRedirect' => array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'login'
),
```

And it's working just fine now. I just wish Cake's documentation had covered this... If it does, I swear I couldn't find it anywhere.